# opencart 2.0 confirm.php getZone Notice: Undefined index: name

Tags: php, opencart2.x

```
if (isset($this->session->data['guest']['payment']['zone_id'])) {
            $data['zone_id'] = $this->session->data['guest']['payment']['zone_id'];         
        } else {
            $data['zone_id'] = '';
        }
        $this->load->model('localisation/zone');

        $zone_info = $this->model_localisation_zone->getZone($data['zone_id']);

        $data['zone'] = $zone_info['name'];
```

I get the data in this way, but fails Notice: Undefined index: name 
I work file catalog/controller/checkout/confirm.php
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
if(isset($this->session->data['payment_address']['zone'])){
  $data['zone'] = $this->session->data['payment_address']['zone'];
}else{
  $data['zone'] = '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check $data['zone_id'] is receiving some value or not

> echo "< pre>"; print_r($data['zone_id']);die;

if $data['zone_id'] is empty then check this `$this->session->data['guest']['payment']['zone_id'];`

or

if  `$data['zone_id']` is receiving value then add this

```
if (isset($this->session->data['guest']['payment']['zone_id'])) {
            $data['zone_id'] = $this->session->data['guest']['payment']['zone_id'];         
        } else {
            $data['zone_id'] = '';
        }
        $this->load->model('localisation/zone');

        $zone_info = $this->model_localisation_zone->getZone($data['zone_id']);

$zone_info['name'] = isset($zone_info['name'])?$zone_info['name']:'';

        $data['zone'] = $zone_info['name'];
```